# Need a simple example of Server-Side Java Script

Tags: javascript

I am not able to find any simple example of server side java script. I don't want to use any node.js or other things.

1. Want to write piece of code only with simple notepad. E.g connecting to database.
2. What are the tags used in HTML to differentiate the server side java script.
3. Once SSJS completed, how to deploy the same on server.

Also, if you know any site which give this information, that would be really gr8.

Comment: You'll need a runtime environment for (server side) JS. Afaik currently Node.JS is the only reasonable choice for that. So you want get around it, if you want to use server side JS.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Did a research & found below info from wiki.

Netscape introduced an implementation of the language for server-side scripting with Netscape Enterprise Server in December, 1995, soon after releasing JavaScript for browsers. Since the mid-2000s, there has been a resurgence of server-side JavaScript implementations, such as Node.js.
So how the people used server side java script prior to Node.js?

The reason for not using Node.js is, my project requires a lot of approval before installing any software or framework. so I wanted the solution without using any framwork.